# 2 point in time line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two times. For example, $t_1$= 0:17, $t_2 = 0:12$, and the time2WasBefore = 0:04, which means that $t_2$ was before now 0:4 minutes. I have to find the nearest situation, when $t_1$ will be one minute before $t_2$. How can I solve it? Bezout and Euclid?

Comment: IF you mean something recurs at $17$ minute intervals and something else recurs at $12$ minute intervals, you are on the right track.  It is very hard to understand the question-I am guessing from your reference to Bezout and Euclid.

Comment: Yes, they are intervals 17 a 12 minutes. I now that it:
12x + (12 - 4 ) = 17y
But I want to algorithm.